# What is the service cycle or interval of the Landing gear of an A380 and 747-8

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, airbus-a380, boeing-747

What is the service cycle or interval of the Landing gear of an A380 and 747-8, i.e how long between service, eg after how many take offs and landings with particular reference to bearing checks and lubrication of the bearings and axles of the wheels

Comment: I'm guessing that this is something done at A or B checks, not at a particular landing/cycle interval.

Comment: Certainly not less than C check, 4000 to 6000 hours depending on the airplane. Airliners only have minor maintenance and inspections (1A, 2A, 3A, etc. - A checks are 500 hours give or take) that can be done on overnights, until C check which is the first time a lot of panels are removed and components get major servicing and functional testing and the plane is down for a week or so.  A task like that could also be based on flight cycles and if not set at a level that allows coordination with C check down time, becomes "out of phase" maintenance and is a pain in the butt for the airline

Comment: 20 wheels and 16 wheels respectively for these two aircrafts on their main landing gears do seem to provide a distributed wait per wheel in the same range as on other aircrafts such as the B777 or the A330. I would say the same maintenance interval as other large aircrafts.

Comment: https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/workgroups/Documents/MCC-2015-MIA/D2_0945-1030_-_Fin_Impact_of_Extending_or_Reducing_Lease_Term_-_Joost_Groenenboom.pdf seems to suggest 10 yearly landing gear shop visits for typical operations for both narrow- and widebodies.